# Nodes in Spherical Harmonics

Tags: wavefunction, hydrogen, spherical-harmonics, rydberg-states

In *Rydberg Atoms book by Thomas F. Gallagher, Page 14*, the author provides the general equation of spherical harmonics which is well-known. He states that there exist $l-m$ nodes in the $\theta$ coordinate, and none in the $\phi$ coordinate. The coordinate system taken by the author is given below in the figure.

[image]

I understand the concept of nodes and how to count them for each orbital. I am trying to visualize the direction of these nodes but I cannot understand how these nodes are in the $\theta$ coordinate not in the $\phi$ coordinate.

Comment: Is the question now explicitly about visualizing complex functions on coordinates that are not cartesian ? Or the fact that there are no nodes in $\phi$ ? I guess from a mathematical viewpoint it is quite clear, right ? $e^{im\phi}$ is never equal to zero.

Comment: I guess they are related. If I can't understand why there are no nodes in the $/phi$ direction, I can't visualize neither.

Comment: But you realised that $e^{im\phi}$ is a complex value and that the absolute value is never zero, but always one. Isn't that the reason that there are no nodes in $\phi$ ? Or am I wrong

Comment: I think so! So if $\phi=0$, Y is never zero?

Comment: Well $e^0 = 1$, but $Y(\theta,\phi)$ can still be zero if the factor with $\theta$ results to 0.